# Why text-align affect child div, but not font-size?

Tags: css

This is basic but I couldn't find what I need.

```
 <div class="coverTitle"><h1> The Best In Town </h1></div>
```

I was thinking that to align the text I need:

```
.coverTitle>h1
{
  text-align:center;
}
```

**but** :

```
  .coverTitle
    {
      text-align:center;
    }
```

also works.

**On the other side**,

```
  .coverTitle
    {
       font-size: 10px;
    }
```

will **not** affect the font size of that child.

How is that some things affect a child and others won't?

Comment: did you inspect with developer tools? my first guess is that some other CSS rule is overiding the one you have given by .coverTitle

Comment: Thanks, i am not sure I get you. how is that text-align will affect the h1, without stating that its h1 (coverTitle>h1{}...)

Comment: Add `>` in your question html div tag after class `<div class="coverTitle"<h1> The Best In Town </h1></div>`. Just a observation.

Comment: @Curnelious  close your `coverTitle` div properly.

Comment: It's closed in the original code, I just removed something for the question and removed it by mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the working snippet below:

```css
.coverTitle.one {
  text-align:center;
}

.coverTitle.two {
  font-size: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="coverTitle one">
  <h1> text-align: center </h1>
</div>

<div class="coverTitle two">
  <h1> font-size: 10px </h1>
</div>
```

`font-size` definitely affects child elements. (More accurately, child elements definitely *inherits* from its parent)

So your claim that `font-size` of parent will not affect the `font-size` of a child is false.

Now see this other example:

```css
.coverTitle.one {
  text-align:center;
}

.coverTitle.two {
  font-size: 10px;
}

.coverTitle.two > h1 {
  font-size: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="coverTitle one">
  <h1> text-align: center </h1>
</div>

<div class="coverTitle two">
  <h1> font-size: 10px </h1>
</div>
```

Notice in the CSS I've added `> h1` to specifically target the child element.

Now, the font-size will not inherit from parent, because you have explicitly set its own font-size.

The takeaway is that most CSS properties of child elements will inherit from its parent if they are not explicitly passed a value.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is because `<h1>` has a default user-agent font size that is larger than normal text. In order to override it, you must explicitly change the font size of all `<h1>`s or within a class:

```css
.some-class {
  font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<div class="some-class">
  <h1>This is a default H1</h1>
  <p>This is normal text.</p>
</div>
```

Now let's explicitly set the font size of the `<h1>`:

```css
.some-class {
  font-size: 18px;
}

.some-class h1 {
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="some-class">
  <h1>This is a default H1</h1>
  <p>This is normal text.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In reality this should work. You forgot a closing tag in your HTML, this can be the cause of the problem. If not, it is possible that another property of your CSS applies and overwrites the "font-size: 10px". You can try this hypothesis by entering "font-size: 10px !important". If it works it is because the property is effectively overwritten elsewhere in your code.

```css
.coverTitle {
  font-size: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="coverTitle"><h1> The Best In Town </h1></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to change the font size of the child element without knowing which heading tag is the child, try this:

```
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6{
    font-size:inherit;
}

.coverTitle
{
   font-size: 10px;
}
```

This will ensure that the child element is receiving the font-size from its parent. If you want to include paragraph tag in the range, just include p after h6. Make sure to insert a comma between h6 and p.

Answer (score 0):

> Why text-align affect child div, but not font-size?

It actually does partially

Now the user-agent(browser) applies some starting point style-sheet to all elements and that varies from browser to another, in the case of chrome the `h1` gets `font-size:2em` this is important to notice, because a `computed values` won't get overridden by inheritance.

When you say

```
.coverTitle
{
   font-size: 10px;
}
```

`div.coverTitle` will get `font-size:10px` but the `h1` will get `font-size:20px` this happens because of the multiplier `2em` the `h1` has by default

## Demo

```css
div {
  font-size: 10px;
}

div>h1 {
  /*   1em = 16px */
  /*   default font-size:2em;  */
  /*   font-size is inherited by default */
  /*   font-size: inherited * default */
  /*   font size becomes */
  /*   font-size:20px; */
}

.helper {
  font-size: 20px;
  /* or */
  /* font-size: calc(10px * 2); */
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>Test</h1>
</div>
<h1 class="helper">Test</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

`h1` is a special tag hence the final font size of this tag is also affected by the emphasis factor added by the browsers as per the HTML specification.

Child tags always inherit the font size from their parents but since the `h1` tag has emphasis, its font size will actually be larger than its siblings and parent, but still derived from the value assigned to the parent.

You can check this behaviour, by adding a `p` tag and `h1` tag inside a `div` and then changing the font size assigned to the `div`. You will see font sizes of both `h1` and `p` tag change, but the `h1` font will actually be bigger and change faster due to emphasis.